# O365 - How to better understand and handle 429 throttling responses

Tags: json, microsoft-graph-api

When making calls to Office 365, a variety of throttling responses can occur.

Here are some examples:

Status code 429:

```
{
"error": {
    "code": "activityLimitReached",
    "innererror": { "code": "throttledRequest" },
    "message": "The request has been throttled",
    "retryAfterSeconds": 0
}
```

Status code 429:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "activityLimitReached",
    "message": "The application or user has been throttled."
  }
}
```

Status code 429:

```
Message [429 TOO MANY REQUESTS]]
```

I suspect that each of these throttled messages may actually refer to different states.

1. Do these messages actually mean different things?
2. The `retry-after` header value is always `120`. Always. Should we do an exponential backoff instead?
3. SharePoint docs around throttling mention adding a special user agent header.  Would this make a difference to calls to Microsoft Graph?

Answer (score 0):

Different endpoints/services have their own throttling rules. Some throttle based on concurrent requests, by the number of requests with a 10-minute window, etc.

For details on how throttling works with Microsoft Graph, and tips for handling `429` messages, I suggest reading [Microsoft Graph throttling guidance](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/concepts/throttling).